# How select value in a "Input"

Tags: jquery

The input is :

```
<input type="button" value="O" name="<?php echo $v[$i]['t']; ?>" onclick="javascript:test_parent();">
```

Suppose there are a lot of button with different attribute name.I need to create a function `test_parent()` and in this function I need to extract the name of button that I clicked. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be your answer

```
    $('input[type="button"]').on('click', function (){
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
alert(name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to avoid the inline js. You can attach an event-listener instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="button"]').on('click', function (){
        alert($(this).attr('name'));
    });
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hjtxp1x4/)**

**Reference**

[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: @Fuffy You can just add this code to the beginning of your js-file. Note the [`$(document).ready`-function](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you.

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="O"
       name="<?php echo $v[$i]['t']; ?>"
       onclick="javascript:test_parent(this);">
```

Javascript

```
function test_parent(input){
    var name = $(input).prop("name");
}
```

See a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/6georz5m/

Answer (score 0):

Selecting Input Value in Input Field, [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/zrosj3kn/)

```
function myFunction() {
    alert(document.getElementById('inputId').value)    
}
```